# An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'db'. - Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to containerize asp.net core + mysql application on docker, however I am getting this error when I run backend container.

> An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'db'. - Docker

Platform and Environment :

- Docker for Windows 10
- Asp.net core 3.1
- MySql 5.7.22
- List item
- Deployed on Linux
- EF Core
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.1

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>(
                    options => options.UseMySql(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"),
                        mySqlOptionsAction => mySqlOptionsAction.EnableRetryOnFailure()
                    ));
}
```

appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySql": "server=db;database=MySqlDbContext;uid=root;pwd=123456;"
  }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN dotnet restore
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","run"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: hello.db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    container_name: hello.web
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: hello.proxy
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: can you try using `container_name` and the name on  `ConnectionStrings` ?  or removing it  and restart ?

Comment: I've tried this one too, same error

Comment: do you have output on db container from when you try to connect?

Comment: do you mean, check if database is working in docker, yes I was able to connect to the database and show all the existing databases.

Comment: I mean run docker logs and see if any logs register while the app is trying to connect to DB if there any clue there ?